# HTTP POST + ANDROID Not Getting response !

Tags: android, post

I am having webservice made with PHP. I am posting parameter and fetching data from the server. It works fine for the small amount of data.

I have one test service which return 10 xml records its working well. The same webservice with all the 160 xml records is not fetching data.

I pasted my code below.. **Is there any limitation in terms of amount of data or do I need to pass any other parameters ?**

```
public void LoadNews(String Url, List<NameValuePair> nvp) {
    InputStream ins = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = nvp;
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        ins = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(ins);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(1024);

        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        String response = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                + new String(baf.toByteArray());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(CommonFunctions.LOGTAG, "ClientProtocolException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(CommonFunctions.LOGTAG, "IOException");
    }
```

I tested same webservice with Firefox + Poster Addon its working fine with.. XML gives CDATA in response.

Comment: Can you provide more details? By "not fetching data" do you mean your webservice isn't returning all the data it is meant to? Otherwise, can you provide some Logcat output?

Comment: Hi dave, HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); in this I am not getting anything in response. When I put watch over response Im getting Status Code 200/OK... That means theres some response but Im not getting anything in ins = response.getEntity().getContent();

Comment: Am I going on right way to get response data ?

Comment: That could be an issue with your web service or network connection rather than an with your code or Android. Have you tried putting the URL into the Android browser and confirming it gets data back?

Comment: Vishal: see my answer below about using `BasicResponseHandler`. That's the cleanest, simplest way to get the HTTP response content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer, but a recommendation - use `BasicResponseHandler` for retrieving HTTP content. It saves all the streaming/buffering nonsense! (i.e. most of your `try` clause)

```
String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler());
```

To make this clearer:

```
public void LoadNews(String Url, List<NameValuePair> nvp) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = nvp;
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        String response = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + 
            httpclient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler());

        /* ... do stuff with response ... */
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(CommonFunctions.LOGTAG, "ClientProtocolException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(CommonFunctions.LOGTAG, "IOException");
    }
}
```

As an addendum, you should **not** be adding the XML header manually - this should be returned in the document by the web service you're using.

Comment: can you please elaborate more ? or any related example ?

Comment: I used this also.. but getting response1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" means no response from webservice

Comment: No, it means your web service returned no data. If there was no response, an exception would have been thrown. You'll need to debug this yourself and check your POST request is correct. You may find it easier to add debugging output to your webservice so you can see exactly what requests are being made by your Android code.

Comment: you might be right but the same webservice with passing count=9 which will return just 9 records will work and if it will be changed to more than 9 ie. 10/15 then theres no response from the same..

Comment: This sounds like a bug with your webservice or the request you're making (such as the values of the name-value pairs).

Comment: Yes even I also think same.. Trying the same with converting to SOAP